Issue with Applying KEDA 2.10.1 YAML with Tolerations on Kubernetes Nodes
I tried to deploy KEDA version 2.10.1 with custom tolerations to ensure that the KEDA resources are scheduled on specific nodes in k8s cluster. The tolerations were configured as follows:
                          tolerations:
                            -   key: "infra"
                                operator: "Exists"
                                effect: "NoSchedule"

However, i encountered an error when applying the configuration with below query :
kubectl apply --server-side -f keda-2.10.1.yaml --validate=false 
Note: The deployment works correctly when the tolerations section is not changed.
I tried to deploy KEDA version 2.10.1 with custom tolerations.
Expected result :
All resources are applied to cluster.
Actual result :
Error message:
Error from server: failed to create typed patch object (/scaledjobs.keda.sh; apiextensions.k8s.io/v1, Kind=CustomResourceDefinition): .spec.versions[0].schema.openAPIV3Schema.properties.spec.properties.jobTargetRef.properties.template.properties.spec.properties.tolerations: expected map, got &{[map[effect:NoSchedule key:infra operator:Exists]]} 
